# Hello, I am a beginner in java and do not understand how to fix this

Tags: java

I understood the error message so that the string linie = null and now my question how do I fix it in the string null even though the code is written correctly so far?
It is a file whose function is to output auto attributesfor a program for a Car dealer.
First the file `"Autos.txt"` (at the end of the codes) is read in order to determine how many cars there are in total in the range and is saved in int zeahler, which is recognized by the spaces in the file. Then as many objects are created as are stored in zeahler and now the attributes of the respective cars are output, however "linie = br2.readLine ();" is marked as a redundant assignment and so the first line in the text file is not read, which causes the error message. At least I thought until I changed it, but nothing had changed. The error message still appeared.

## Class

```
public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        int zaehler = 0;
        String linie;
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\Paul\\Java\\Autohaus\\src\\com\\company\\Autos.txt");
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

            linie = br.readLine();
            while (linie != null) {
                if ("".equals(linie)) {
                    zaehler++;
                }
                linie = br.readLine();
            }
            br.close();


        } catch (IOException ioAusnahme) {
            System.out.println("Datei konnte nicht geöffnet werden.");
        }
        Auto[] sortiment = new Auto[zaehler];

        try {
            FileReader fis2 = new FileReader("C:\\Paul\\Java\\Autohaus\\src\\com\\company\\Autos.txt");
            BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(fis2);

            for (int i = 0; i < zaehler; i++) {
                linie = br2.readLine();
                linie = br2.readLine();
                double preis = Double.parseDouble(linie);
                linie = br2.readLine();
                String modell = linie;
                linie = br2.readLine();
                int baujahr = Integer.parseInt(linie);
                linie = br2.readLine();
                int kilometerstand = Integer.parseInt(linie);
                String farbe = linie;
                sortiment[i] = new Auto(preis, modell, baujahr, kilometerstand, farbe);
            }
            br2.close();

        } catch (IOException ioAusnahme) {
            System.out.println("Datei konnte nicht geöffnet werden.");
        }

        for (Auto element2 : sortiment) {
            System.out.println(element2.getPreis());
            System.out.println(element2.getModell());
            System.out.println(element2.getBaujahr());
            System.out.println(element2.getKilometerstand());
            System.out.println(element2.getFarbe() + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

## Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
    at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
    at java.base/java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:549)
    at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:43)
```

## Input file

*This is the file to be read from.*

```
12000
VW Golf
2014
45355
blau

9000
Renault Megane
2010
76456
grün

14000
Ford Focus
2012
34678
grau
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Note that this is an English-only site, so please post your question in english. Also please include the code and debug inputs as text, not images.

Comment: First, the question should be in English in this group. Second, you shouldn't link to images, include the code and errors and data inside the question in formatted text. And third, you're almost certainly trying to convert a blank line or a text string into a double, which is causing this exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < zaehler; i++) {
    linie = br2.readLine();
    linie = br2.readLine();
    double preis = Double.parseDouble(linie);
    linie = br2.readLine();
    String modell = linie;
    linie = br2.readLine();
    int baujahr = Integer.parseInt(linie);
    linie = br2.readLine();
    int kilometerstand = Integer.parseInt(linie);
    String farbe = linie;
    sortiment[i] = new Auto(preis, modell, baujahr, kilometerstand, farbe);
}
```

as a first line you have:

```
linie = br2.readLine();
linie = br2.readLine();
```

You should move one of them, as a LAST line of your loop to "skip" empty line. Added also more comments to make it clear (and "divided for sections"):

```
for (int i = 0; i < zaehler; i++) {
    // Read price
    linie = br2.readLine();
    double preis = Double.parseDouble(linie);

    // Read model
    linie = br2.readLine();
    String modell = linie;

    // Read year of production
    linie = br2.readLine();
    int baujahr = Integer.parseInt(linie);

    // Read mileage
    linie = br2.readLine();
    int kilometerstand = Integer.parseInt(linie);

    // Read color
    linie = br2.readLine();
    String farbe = linie;

    // Build "Auto" and add to array
    sortiment[i] = new Auto(preis, modell, baujahr, kilometerstand, farbe);

    // Skip empty line
    linie = br2.readLine();
}
```

Or with catching more exceptions and filling fields in `Auto` withing the loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < zaehler; i++) {
    Auto auto = new Auto();

    // Read price
    try {
        linie = br2.readLine();
        auto.setPreis(Double.parseDouble(linie));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Read model
    try {
        linie = br2.readLine();
        auto.setModell(linie);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Read year of production
    try {
        linie = br2.readLine();
        auto.setBaujahr(Integer.parseInt(linie));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Read mileage
    try {
        linie = br2.readLine();
        auto.setKilometerstand(Integer.parseInt(linie));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Read color
    try {
        linie = br2.readLine();
        auto.setFarbe(linie);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Add auto to array
    sortiment[i] = auto;

    // Skip empty line
    linie = br2.readLine();
}
```

## Full working example:

```
package src;

import java.io.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Auto[] autos = readAutos();

        for (Auto auto : autos) {
            System.out.println(auto);
        }
    }

    private static Auto[] readAutos() {
        Auto[] output = new Auto[0];

        try {
            BufferedReader numberReader = getBufferedReader();
            int numberOfCars = calculateNumberOfCars(numberReader);
            System.out.println("Number of cars: " + numberOfCars);

            BufferedReader carReader = getBufferedReader();
            output = parseInput(carReader, numberOfCars);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return output;
    }

    private static BufferedReader getBufferedReader() throws FileNotFoundException {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("autos.txt");
        InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream);
        return new BufferedReader(streamReader);
    }

    private static int calculateNumberOfCars(BufferedReader reader) {
        String line;
        int counter = 0;

        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                if (line.equals("")) {
                    counter++;
                }
            }

            counter++;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return counter;
    }

    private static Auto[] parseInput(BufferedReader reader, int numberOfCars) throws IOException {
        Auto[] output = new Auto[numberOfCars];
        String line;
        int number = 0;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            Auto auto = new Auto();

            // Read price
            auto.setPreis(Double.parseDouble(line));

            // Read model
            line = reader.readLine();
            auto.setModell(line);

            // Read year of production
            line = reader.readLine();
            auto.setBaujahr(Integer.parseInt(line));

            // Read mileage
            line = reader.readLine();
            auto.setKilometerstand(Integer.parseInt(line));

            // Read color
            line = reader.readLine();
            auto.setFarbe(line);

            // Add auto to array
            output[number] = auto;
            number++;

            // Skip empty line
            reader.readLine();
        }

        return output;
    }
}
```

for model class:

```
package src;

public class Auto {
    private double preis;
    private String modell;
    private int baujahr;
    private int kilometerstand;
    private String farbe;

    public double getPreis() {
        return preis;
    }

    public void setPreis(double preisl) {
        this.preis = preisl;
    }

    public String getModell() {
        return modell;
    }

    public void setModell(String modell) {
        this.modell = modell;
    }

    public int getBaujahr() {
        return baujahr;
    }

    public void setBaujahr(int baujahr) {
        this.baujahr = baujahr;
    }

    public int getKilometerstand() {
        return kilometerstand;
    }

    public void setKilometerstand(int kilometerstand) {
        this.kilometerstand = kilometerstand;
    }

    public String getFarbe() {
        return farbe;
    }

    public void setFarbe(String farbe) {
        this.farbe = farbe;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Auto{" +
                "preis=" + preis +
                ", modell='" + modell + '\'' +
                ", baujahr=" + baujahr +
                ", kilometerstand=" + kilometerstand +
                ", farbe='" + farbe + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212512/discussion-on-answer-by-boken-hello-i-am-a-beginner-in-java-and-do-not-understa).